# laplace transform of two different functions

Tags: functions, laplace-transform

Is it possible for two  different functions to have the same laplace transform?.In this sense how do we know that the inverse laplace transform gives exclusively one function?.if it is not possible does anyone know how this can be proven?

Comment: See: https://sites.math.washington.edu//~marshall/math_135/UniqueLaplace.pdf